# Teradata SQL Derived table data redistribution

Tags: sql, performance, teradata, sql-tuning, derived-table

This is once again a a question for SQL Pundits. 
I can create derived tables in Teradata using these approaches

```
 - With ( __,__)
(select statement ) alias 
query 
-- select ____ from a , ( select statement ) b  < Join condition )
```

I wondered in either of the cases HOW does the  Data distribution ( for the DT )  take place . Is there a rule out here ? Is there some way I can tweak the DT so that I can get re-distribution based on the key(s) I want - the same functionality as VT But I guess, it avoids having a new CT statement and also you loose stats facility ( which I can in some situations afford to loose if its not changing the explain )

Comment: your sample query is using with , are you creating CTE using WITH clause . You are asking about DT , but in DT with and recursion is not supported.  Please read here http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1146_111A/ch01.032.128.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EXPLAIN` the query and you will see the distribution, it's not the keys you want, it's usually based on the following join, e.g. *distributed by the hash code of (your join columns)*.

Using a VT you can force a specific order, so of course there are cases were a Volatile Table might be better, but unless you need the same result in subsequent queries you should check the optimizer's plan using DTs/CTEs first.

Comment: Thanks Dieter. Here another one that was a bit  "drainy" because here I redistributed by dims as many times its joined to fct. e.g. f1.c1=d1.c1 and f1.c2=d1.c1 and a LOT of these are LOJ and some are IJ's but different fct column with the SAME dimension column referring to one below

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33231402/multiple-table-aliases-between-fact-and-dimension-teradata-sql-joins-sql-tuni